# Expected argument of type array, entity given

Tags: forms, symfony, entity, symfony4, easyadmin

I use Symfony 4 and the bundle easy admin to create a form with multiple collection, here is my code :

**Produit.yaml**

```
easy_admin:
  entities:
    Produit:
      class: App\Entity\Produit
      templates:
        new: 'security/custom_produit.html.twig'
        edit: 'security/custom_produit.html.twig'
      form:
        fields:
          - nom
          - {property: 'fiche_technique_file', label: 'Fiche technique', type: 'vich_file'}
          - categorie
          - { property: 'modele1', label: 'Modèle 1', type: 'collection', type_options: {entry_type: 'App\Form\Modele1Type', allow_add: true, allow_delete: true, by_reference: false} }
      list:
          fields: ['nom', {property: 'fiche_technique', label: 'Fiche technique'}, {property: 'categorie', label: 'Catégorie'},
                   {property: 'modele1', label: 'Modèle 1'}
```

**Modele1Type.php**

```
class Modele1Type extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('intro', CKEditorType::class)
            ->add('caract_tech', CKEditorType::class, [
                'label' => 'Caractéristique technique'
            ])
            ->add('applications', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('info_comp_1', CKEditorType::class, [
                'label' => 'Info complémentaire 1'
            ])
            ->add('info_comp_2', CKEditorType::class, [
                'label' => 'Info complémentaire 2'
            ])
            ->add('info_comp_3', CKEditorType::class, [
                'label' => 'Info complémentaire 3'
            ])
            ->add('galerie_photo', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => MultipleImgModele1Type::class,
                'prototype' => true,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'label' => false,
            ])
            ->add('avantages', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => AvantageType::class,
                'prototype' => true,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'label' => false,
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Modele1::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Produit.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProduitRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable()
 */
class Produit
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $fiche_technique;

    /**
     * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize = "5M",
     *     mimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "application/x-pdf"},
     *     mimeTypesMessage = "Veuillez envoyer un fichier PDF valide"
     * )
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="produit_fiche_tech", fileNameProperty="fiche_technique")
     */
    private $fiche_technique_file;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updated_at;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Categorie", inversedBy="produits")
     */
    private $categorie;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Modele1", inversedBy="produits", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="modele1_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $modele1;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->updated_at = new \DateTime();
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        $res = $this->nom;
        if($this->modele1 != null) {
            $res .= " - Modèle 1";
        } else if($this->modele2 != null) {
            $res .= " - Modèle 2";
        } else if($this->modele3 != null) {
            $res .= " - Modèle 3";
        }
        return $res;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFicheTechnique(): ?string
    {
        return $this->fiche_technique;
    }

    public function setFicheTechnique(?string $fiche_technique): self
    {
        $this->fiche_technique = $fiche_technique;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updated_at;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(?\DateTimeInterface $updated_at): self
    {
        $this->updated_at = $updated_at;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFicheTechniqueFile()
    {
        return $this->fiche_technique_file;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $fiche_technique_file
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function setFicheTechniqueFile(?File $fiche_technique_file): void
    {
        $this->fiche_technique_file = $fiche_technique_file;
        if($fiche_technique_file) {
            $this->updated_at = new \DateTime();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCategorie(): ?Categorie
    {
        return $this->categorie;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $categorie
     */
    public function setCategorie(?Categorie $categorie): void
    {
        $this->categorie = $categorie;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getModele1(): ?Modele1
    {
        return $this->modele1;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $modele1
     */
    public function setModele1($modele1): self
    {
        if(empty(array_values($modele1)[0])) {
            $this->modele1 = null;
        } else {
            $this->modele1 = array_values($modele1)[0];
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Modele1.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Modele1Repository")
 */
class Modele1
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $intro;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $caract_tech;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $applications;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $info_comp_1;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $info_comp_2;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $info_comp_3;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Produit", mappedBy="modele1", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $produits;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MultipleImgModele1", mappedBy="modele1", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $galerie_photo;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Avantage", mappedBy="modele1")
     */
    private $avantages;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->produits = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->galerie_photo = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->avantages = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getIntro(): ?string
    {
        return $this->intro;
    }

    public function setIntro(string $intro): self
    {
        $this->intro = $intro;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCaractTech(): ?string
    {
        return $this->caract_tech;
    }

    public function setCaractTech(string $caract_tech): self
    {
        $this->caract_tech = $caract_tech;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getApplications(): ?string
    {
        return $this->applications;
    }

    public function setApplications(string $applications): self
    {
        $this->applications = $applications;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInfoComp1(): ?string
    {
        return $this->info_comp_1;
    }

    public function setInfoComp1(?string $info_comp_1): self
    {
        $this->info_comp_1 = $info_comp_1;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInfoComp2(): ?string
    {
        return $this->info_comp_2;
    }

    public function setInfoComp2(?string $info_comp_2): self
    {
        $this->info_comp_2 = $info_comp_2;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInfoComp3(): ?string
    {
        return $this->info_comp_3;
    }

    public function setInfoComp3(?string $info_comp_3): self
    {
        $this->info_comp_3 = $info_comp_3;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Produit
     */
    public function getProduits(): Collection
    {
        return $this->produits;
    }

    public function addProduit(Produit $produits): self
    {
        if (!$this->produits->contains($produits)) {
            $this->produits[] = $produits;
            $produits->setModele1($this);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProduit(Produit $produits): self
    {
        if ($this->produits->contains($produits)) {
            $this->produits->removeElement($produits);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($produits->getModele1() === $this) {
                $produits->setModele1(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|MultipleImgModele1[]
     */
    public function getGaleriePhoto(): Collection
    {
        return $this->galerie_photo;
    }

    public function addGaleriePhoto(MultipleImgModele1 $galeriePhoto): self
    {
        if (!$this->galerie_photo->contains($galeriePhoto)) {
            $this->galerie_photo[] = $galeriePhoto;
            $galeriePhoto->setModele1($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeGaleriePhoto(MultipleImgModele1 $galeriePhoto): self
    {
        if ($this->galerie_photo->contains($galeriePhoto)) {
            $this->galerie_photo->removeElement($galeriePhoto);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($galeriePhoto->getModele1() === $this) {
                $galeriePhoto->setModele1(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAvantages(): Collection
    {
        return $this->avantages;
    }

    public function addAvantage(Avantage $avantages): self
    {
        if (!$this->avantages->contains($avantages)) {
            $this->avantages[] = $avantages;
            $avantages->setModele1($this);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAvantage(Avantage $avantages): self
    {
        if ($this->avantages->contains($avantages)) {
            $this->avantages->removeElement($avantages);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($avantages->getModele1() === $this) {
                $avantages->setModele1(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**custom_produit.html.twig**

```
{% extends '@EasyAdmin/default/edit.html.twig' %}

{% block head_custom_stylesheets %}
    {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    {% block entity_form %}
        {{ form_start(form) }}
            <div class="container cont-modele-produit-admin mb-4">
                <div class="accordion" id="accordionModeles">
                    <div class="row mb-4">
                        {% for model in form.modele1.vars.prototype %}
                             <div class="col-md-12 mt-3">
                                 {% if model.vars.name == "galerie_photo" %}
                                     <fieldset class="p-4">
                                         <legend>Galerie Photos</legend>
                                        {{ form_row(model) }}
                                     </fieldset>
                                 {% endif %}
                                 {% if model.vars.name == "avantages" %}
                                     <fieldset class="p-4">
                                         <legend>Avantages</legend>
                                         {{ form_row(model) }}
                                     </fieldset>
                                 {% endif %}
                                 {{ form_label(model)  }}
                                 {{ form_widget(model)  }}
                             </div>
                         {% endfor %}
                         {% do form.modele1.setRendered %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}

{% block body_custom_javascript %}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}
```

In the setModele1 function in the Produit entity, I had to do a little update to get the Modele1 entity data because it give me an array like that :

```
Produit.php on line 180:
array:1 [▼
  "__name__" => Modele1^ {#2564 ▼
    -id: null
    -intro: "<p>test</p>"
    -caract_tech: "<p>test</p>"
    -applications: "test"
    -info_comp_1: null
    -info_comp_2: null
    -info_comp_3: null
    -produits: ArrayCollection^ {#2577 ▶}
    -galerie_photo: ArrayCollection^ {#2806 ▶}
    -avantages: ArrayCollection^ {#2804 ▶}
  }
]
```

it returned me an error because it should get the Modele1 Entity instead of an array, and now when I try to edit a Produit that have a Modele1 it give me this error :
*Expected argument of type "array or (\Traversable and \ArrayAccess)", "Proxies__CG__\App\Entity\Modele1" given*

So why do I need to give an array instead of the Modele1 entity to get all the data and put it in the form to edit then ?

Sorry for my bad english I hope you will all undestand what I wanted to do ^^

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: I also noticed that the getModele1() return null content when I try to edit the Produit entity that has a Modele1. Even if there are data in the Modele1 entity in the database...

Comment: your properties on Produit that (can) have multiple entities (like modele) - and accordingly for Modele1 - should **not** expose the property directly on its getters, but instead assume it to be of type ArrayCollection and call `toArray()` to get their items.

Comment: _So why do I need to give an array instead of the Modele1 entity to get all the data and put it in the form to edit then ?_ 1. The error suggests EXATLY that an entity is given probably to `array_values` which expects an ARRAY. 2. The Form `Modele1Type` does not include a field that represents the `$produits` therefore it unclear when `setModele1` is actually called. 3. When posting an Entity, try reduce it only to the involved properties and not ALL properties...